# Apache2 Not Running

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2, fpm

I'm running an Apache2 LAMP server with Ubuntu 18.04 and suddenly without a warning, the Apache stops running. I tried figuring out the problem with `sudo service apache2 status` and it shows the following:

```
sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-03 13:07:40 UTC; 1h 6min ago
  Process: 55939 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 128448 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 03 13:07:40 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 03 13:07:40 localhost apachectl[55939]: Action 'start' failed.
Sep 03 13:07:40 localhost apachectl[55939]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Sep 03 13:07:40 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 03 13:07:40 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 03 13:07:40 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The first thing I do is try to start it manually with `sudo apachectl restart` which results in the following:

```
sudo apachectl restart
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

So I check the log with `sudo view /var/log/apache2/error.log` and it shows a very long list as below:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Sep 03 06:25:03.860913 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 128448] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 06:25:03.860996 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 128448] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 06:25:03.861009 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 128448] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 06:25:03.861060 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 128448] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 06:25:03.861077 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 128448] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Mon Sep 03 06:25:03.861086 2018] [:emerg] [pid 128448] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Mon Sep 03 06:41:32.662021 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 53226] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 06:41:32.662102 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 53226] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 06:41:32.662112 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 53226] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 06:41:32.662122 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 53226] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 06:41:32.662127 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 53226] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon Sep 03 13:05:09.612981 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55512] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 13:05:09.613049 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55512] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:05:09.613058 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55512] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:05:09.613068 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55512] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 13:05:09.613072 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55512] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon Sep 03 13:07:40.617846 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55942] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 13:07:40.618439 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55942] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:07:40.618451 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55942] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:07:40.618461 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55942] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 13:07:40.618466 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 55942] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon Sep 03 13:14:43.673776 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56048] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 13:14:43.673881 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56048] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:14:43.673895 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56048] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:14:43.673918 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56048] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 13:14:43.673924 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56048] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon Sep 03 13:24:44.627730 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56066] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 13:24:44.627812 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56066] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:24:44.627822 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56066] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:24:44.627839 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56066] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 13:24:44.627845 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56066] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon Sep 03 13:50:11.691451 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56308] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
[Mon Sep 03 13:50:11.691543 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56308] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: DH PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:50:11.691552 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56308] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: EC PARAMETERS) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Mon Sep 03 13:50:11.691569 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56308] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Mon Sep 03 13:50:11.691574 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56308] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon Sep 03 14:07:10.776987 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 56364] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for hailiga.org:443
```

I have tried to `phpdismod` the three error modules and it didn't work. I am running PHP 7.2 and php7.0-fpm, for SSL I have Let's Encrypt Certbot installed.

Can someone out there please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, a corrupted code in my apache config file.

For those who have the same problem here's how to fix it:

1. Go to Apache2 sites-available directory using `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`
2. Disable ALL config files using `sudo a2dissite example.com.conf example-2.com.conf ...` (Ignore the `systemctl reload apache2` now, we will get to it later)
3. Enable the default config files using `sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf`
4. Reload Apache2 with `sudo systemctl reload apache2`
5. Enable the config files one by one to find out which one is corrupted using `sudo a2ensite test-1.conf` and reload apache using `sudo systemctl reload apache2` and finally test if it is working with `sudo service apache2 status`
6. Once you found the file edit it, fix the problem and off to enable all the config files! Be sure to disable the default using `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`, check the Apache is running with `sudo service apache2 status`.

There you have it! That's how I fix it anyway. Oh, the disabling and enabling config files might result in pointing to the wrong directory, when you enabled all of them back it should return to normal.

Have a great day :D